# Loading txt file with file function in php

Tags: php

I am having a problem with loading a .txt file in PHP. My .txt and my php file are in the same directory on the server.

Directory structure:

```
/common/stack.php
/common/stopwords.txt

/abc.php
```

stack.php content:

```
 <?php 

$stopwords = file('stopwords.txt'); 

print_r($stopwords);

?>
```

Surfing to : `http://localhost/common/stack.php` prints the content of stopwords.txt **correctly**.

The problem is when I include stack.php in abc.php i get the following error:

> Warning: file(stopwords.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/common/stack.php

Comment: The relative path is probably wrong since `file()` is called relative to `/` not `/common`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the current working directory is the one of the script that is being called - at least, by default.

Try this:

```
$stopwords = file(__DIR__."/stopwords.txt");
```

This will load the stopwords file from the directory of the current (included) file, which is very useful in general for loading dependent files.